# How to Bind List Item column to drop down list in sharepoint using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a two lists called "Courses", "Instructors". "Courses" list contains following columns.

```
CourseName   Duration   
----------------------
 Sharepoint   60days 
  MSBI        45days 
  .Net        90days 
  Java        50days
```

Instructors list contains following columns

```
 Instructor   Course   
---------------------
  John       Sharepoint 
  Mike       MSBI 
  Bob        Java
```

I want to add "CourseName" column to drop down list, that should implement in webpart.
When we select any course from that drop down, we should show the name of the instructor in the label.
Initially I tried to add a drop down to the webpart to show the **CourseName** column with following code. But I failed to create.

```
DropDownList drpList;
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            drpList = new DropDownList();
            SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;

            SPList list1 = web.Lists["Courses"];
            var listitems = list1.Fields["Course Name"];
            drpList.DataSource = listitems;
            drpList.DataTextField = "Course Name";
            drpList.DataValueField = "Course Name";
            drpList.DataBind();
            Controls.Add(drpList);
        }
```

Can any one suggest me the right way to do it!!

New Implementation.
I tried with following code

```
DropDownList drpList;
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            drpList = new DropDownList();
            SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            ArrayList myarr = new ArrayList();
            myarr.Add(1);
            myarr.Add(2);
            SPSiteDataQuery dataquery = new SPSiteDataQuery();
            dataquery.Lists = string.Format("<Lists><List ID={0} /></Lists>",web.Lists["Courses"].ID);
            dataquery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Course Name\"/>";
            DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(dataquery);
            drpList.DataTextField = "Course Name";
            drpList.DataValueField = "Course Name";
            drpList.DataSource = dt;
            drpList.DataBind();
            Controls.Add(drpList);
        }
```

Drop downlist is appearing but with no data. I think there is mistake in the CAML query. Can any one correct me please!!

Answer (score 1):

The post that Lukasz M is referring to was written by myself.

Firstly, do you *need* to have two separate lists? Can you not have just one list called **Courses**, with the following columns: ***CourseName, Duration, Instructor ***?****** Then you can apply a CAML query that basically does something like this: If the CourseName = "SharePoint", then display the value John from the Instructor Column? If you had this list setup as I have described (all 3 columns in one list), then the code would look like the following (placed in **Page_Load** event):

```
    SPListItemCollection itemCol = null;
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursharepointsite");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList list = web.Lists["Courses"]; //Name of your List with Courses
    SPQuery qryCourse = new SPQuery();
    //This checks what you have selected in the drop-down list (assuming it's called dropList)
    qryCourse.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + dropList.SelectedItem.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
    qryCourse.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Instructor'/>"; //You want the Instructor Column to display

    try
    {
        itemCol = list.GetItems(qryCourse);
        foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
        {
          //Display the Instructor value in your label 
          lblInstructorName.Text = item["Instructor"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        lblInstructorName.Text = "Some Kind of Error!";
    }
```

Please note, you will still need to use the code in my previous post **[Retrieve SharePoint List Data and bind this to a dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999269/retrieve-sharepoint-list-data-and-bind-this-to-a-dropdownlist)** to bind the **dropList** field so that it retrieves its values from the Sharepoint list called **Courses** as Lukasz M has suggested. That will also go in the **Page_Load** event (before the code I've wriiten above). Hope that helps Mihir!

Comment: Hi Mihir - Not received a response from you. I take it you've resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question on SO: [Retrieve SharePoint List Data and bind this to a dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999269/retrieve-sharepoint-list-data-and-bind-this-to-a-dropdownlist). It seems to work exactly as you want it to. According to that code, the data source of the drop down list should be set like this: `drpList.DataSource = list1.Items;`. Please also note that the code is added in `Page_Load` method.

Comment: @Lukasz.. it is not working. First I tried with that one before posting this question.

Comment: What error do you get or describe what exactly is not working when using this code (as described in the answer I linked to)? Have you put this code in `Page_Load` method? If it's working for someone and not working for you, there probably is a difference somewhere, in code or data provided, so I'm trying to find what difference it is :).

Comment: Looking at your question again... Are you using SharePoint 2007 or 2010?

Comment: Have you been debugging this code? If not, please verify if there are any items in `list.Items` just after the line `drpList.DataSource = list.Items;`. It's worth checking, because there may be some access restrictions in the SharePoint to that particular list that prevent your user to access the list (or laternatively just verify if you have required permissions to that list).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use provider and consumer webpart.
It might be your answer

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx)

thanks